# How to prevent a word entered as password by user being interpreted as command on my code?

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to writing batch scripts and I keep getting an error. Basically the code I have written is supposed to be an alternative interface for creating accounts and elevating them to administrator status. So far I have written:

```
@echo off
echo Account Name:
set /p name=
set nameacc = %name%
echo Account Password:
set /p password=
set passacc = %password%
net user /add "%name%" & "%password%"   
cls
echo Account %name%,password: %password% created
pause
echo Would you like to elevate to Admin privelages? Y/N
set /p choice=
if '%choice%' == 'Y' goto A 
if '%choice%' == 'N' goto B
:A 
echo Elevating your Account...
net localgroup administrators %nameacc /add
echo Account created... Have fun..
pause
=exit
:B
exit
```

One problem I have is that if the entered password is the same as a console command, it returns the help screen for that command.

Answer (score 5):

That's because `&` is a way to run two separate commands on one line.

```
net user /add "%name%" & "%password%"
```

Means run `net user ...` then run the command that %password% expands to

I can't test it at the moment, but I think the syntax is simply

```
net user /add %name% %password%
```

As a side note, I'd change your admin choice to

```
if /i '%choice:~0,1%' == 'Y' (goto A) else (goto B)
```

The way you have it, you're more likely to mistakenly make admin accounts.

Comment: The usage of the variable in the `IF` statement is wrong, since you purposely change the answer, then validate it. The answer must be 'Y' or 'N'. What you do is take the first letter of the answer, which is technically incorrect.

Comment: How the error is handled is up to the coder.  In a yes/no question, an answer beginning with y is a "yes" to me for a simple script. It's better than anything other than a capital N defaults to admin

Answer (score 3):

Variables being set like this include spaces in the variable name and the content

```
set passacc = %password%
```

Use this method instead:

```
set "passacc=%password%"
```

Additionally, this line is missing a `%`

```
net localgroup administrators %nameacc /add
```

Comment: Don't need to put " around a fixed name, like `set "variable"`. You're unnecessarily setting the quote at a place that causes more confusion than anything else. Use `set variable="%other_variable%"`

Comment: @tvCa Your method includes the quotes in the variable.  That's fine if you want quotes there, but in very many cases you **do not** want to alter the variable because you intend to use it to append values.  It's something that is essential to know when using environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:

- I don't know if "Y" is the default answer, if it isn't you must catch other answers
- Other answers may include "y" and "n", you should catch them
- I removed quite some whitespaces, be very careful with them
- `goto :EOF` may be an alternative to `EXIT`, the first one exits the current script, the last one exits any script, child or parent
- You're not doing anything in `:B`, if that is on purpose, you can exit in the `IF` statement already
- If you want to fill variable `nameacc` just use `set /p nameacc=` no need to involve other variables

  ```
  @echo off
  echo Account Name:
  set /p name=
  set nameacc=%name%
  echo Account Password:
  set /p password=
  set passacc=%password%
  net user /add "%name%" "%password%"
  cls
  echo Account "%name%",password: "%password%" created
  pause
  echo Would you like to elevate to Admin privelages? Y/N
  set /p choice=
  if '%choice%'=='Y' goto :A
  if '%choice%'=='N' goto :B
  goto :wronganswer

  :A 
  echo Elevating your Account...
  net localgroup administrators %nameacc% /add
  echo Account created... Have fun..
  pause
  exit

  :B
  exit

  :wronganswer
  echo Wrong answer
  goto :EOF
  ```

Comment: Further to your comment above in my question - your code will fail if the password contains an `&` or other poison characters. The double quotes protect the variables from that situation.